# Slangs for drugs

Tags: word-request, slang

I'm translating a story of mine and the characters use lots of slang words for four different drugs.
LSD, Ecstasy, Cocaine and Marijuana.

I need slang terms for this drugs, and, the more generic each, the better.

Comment: Not all 'off topic' questions are bad questions! +1

Comment: Useful: http://www.noslang.com/drugs/dictionary/ not one word but slang words for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with [the Urban Dictionary's entry for 'drugs'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Drugs) and then look up each drug you want slang terms for.

I suggest the Urban Dictionary because it contains many slang terms that most dictionaries do not contain. And these terms are usually up to date.

For example, the entry (on mobile at least) for [marijuana](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=marijuana) contains links to

weed
pot
joint
mary jane
grass
smoke

which are all slang for marijuana.